# Почему контроллер (stm32l476rg) падает в hard fault?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

Пытаюсь запустить программу моргания светодиодами на STM32L476RG. Программа успешно прошивается и запускается. Выполняется начальная инициализация, но когда программа делает переход на *main()* -- получаю hard fault:

> signal handler called () at 0xfffffff9

Для прошивки использую openocd. Использую библиотеку libopencm3, поэтому скрипт линкера выглядит так:

```
MEMORY
{
   rom (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 1024K
   ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
}

INCLUDE libopencm3_stm32l4.ld
```

Полный скрипт **libopencm3_stm32l4.ld** ниже.

```
/*
 * This file is part of the libopencm3 project.
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2009 Uwe Hermann <uwe@hermann-uwe.de>
 *
 * This library is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * along with this library.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

/* Generic linker script for STM32 targets using libopencm3. */

/* Memory regions must be defined in the ld script which includes this one. */

/* Enforce emmition of the vector table. */
EXTERN (vector_table)

/* Define the entry point of the output file. */
ENTRY(reset_handler)

/* Define sections. */
SECTIONS
{
    .text : {
        *(.vectors) /* Vector table */
        *(.text*)   /* Program code */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.rodata*) /* Read-only data */
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >rom

    /* C++ Static constructors/destructors, also used for __attribute__
     * ((constructor)) and the likes */
    .preinit_array : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __preinit_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
        __preinit_array_end = .;
    } >rom
    .init_array : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __init_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
        KEEP (*(.init_array))
        __init_array_end = .;
    } >rom
    .fini_array : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        __fini_array_start = .;
        KEEP (*(.fini_array))
        KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
        __fini_array_end = .;
    } >rom

    /*
     * Another section used by C++ stuff, appears when using newlib with
     * 64bit (long long) printf support
     */
    .ARM.extab : {
        *(.ARM.extab*)
    } >rom
    .ARM.exidx : {
        __exidx_start = .;
        *(.ARM.exidx*)
        __exidx_end = .;
    } >rom

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;

    .data : {
        _data = .;
        *(.data*)   /* Read-write initialized data */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _edata = .;
    } >ram AT >rom
    _data_loadaddr = LOADADDR(.data);

    .bss : {
        *(.bss*)    /* Read-write zero initialized data */
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _ebss = .;
    } >ram

    /*
     * The .eh_frame section appears to be used for C++ exception handling.
     * You may need to fix this if you're using C++.
     */
    /DISCARD/ : { *(.eh_frame) }

    . = ALIGN(4);
    end = .;
}

PROVIDE(_stack = ORIGIN(ram) + LENGTH(ram));
```

Параметры компилятора:

> arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -march=armv7e-m -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -munaligned-access -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g3 ...

Собственно как можно локализировать источник проблемы? Где собака зарыта?

Comment: Пойдите на специализированный ресурс типа электроникса. Есть стандартный метод определения точки из который программа улетела в хард-фаулт. Наиболее вероятно в вашем случае это обращение в регистры НЕзатактированной периферии, но может и с памятью что не так.

Answer (score 3):

В первую очередь откройте шестнадцатеричным редактором готовый бинарный файл и посмотрите, действительно ли в начале программы расположена таблица прерываний. В ней первое слово должно быть равно 0x20000000 + размер оперативной памяти - это указатель стека. Дальнейшие слова - указатели прерываний, и скорее всего, большинство из них должны указывать на один и тот же адрес - адрес метки DefaultHandler. Он должен иметь вид приблизительно 0x0800.... Если всё в порядке, идём дальше.

[далее - догадки] В скрипте линкера присутствует переменная vector_table, которой нигде не присваивается значение. Скорее всего, она используется в стартовом ассемблерном коде программы для копирования таблицы прерываний в оперативную память, но так как этой переменной не присвоено значение, копирование происходит непонятно куда. Скорее всего, подразумевалось следующее:

```
.text : {
    vector_table = .
    *(.vectors) /* Vector table */
    *(.text*)   /* Program code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata*) /* Read-only data */
    . = ALIGN(4);
} >rom
```

Чтобы определить точно, нужно смотреть ассемблерные листинги. Поскольку вы располагаете отладчиком, вы можете их протрассировать и найти место, где (возможно) происходит копирование.

Если причина не в этом, можно также проверить таблицу прерываний, действительно ли она подходит вашему контроллеру.

Answer (score 1):

Возможные причины HardFault:

- [Debugging a HardFault on Cortex-M](https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/debugger/debugging-a-hardfault-on-cortex-m/)
- [Cortex-M3 / M4 Hard Fault Handler](http://blog.frankvh.com/2011/12/07/cortex-m3-m4-hard-fault-handler/)

Методы отладки:

- [Debugging a Hard Fault](https://community.nxp.com/message/630605)
- [Debugging Hard Fault & Other Exceptions  on ARM Cortex-M3 and ARM
  Cortex-M4 microcontrollers](http://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html)
- [Debugging Hard Faults on ARM Cortex-M](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/11/24/debugging-hard-faults-on-arm-cortex-m/)
- [Developing a Generic Hard Fault handler for ARM
  Cortex-M3/Cortex-M4](https://blog.feabhas.com/2013/02/developing-a-generic-hard-fault-handler-for-arm-cortex-m3cortex-m4/)

Сам когда-то возился (причины были в некорректных указателях, порче памяти и переполнении стека). В вашем случае возможно что-то из 2-й ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

В основном эта ошибка возникает при неправильной работе с памятью (обращение за границу допустимой области памяти).

Надо убедиться, что:

- размер стека достаточен;
- не используется неинициализированный указатель.

Answer (score 0):

> signal handler called () at 0xfffffff9

Для тех, кто будет искать эту строку, описываю мое решение.

У меня это было по причине не пропаянной ноги `BOOT0`. Осциллографом тыкаю (прижимаю) - там `0`. запускаю код - сабж. Куда смотреть на `Cortex-M0` (у него таблица прерываний всегда на адресе `0`): смотрим отладчиком область памяти `0`. Если там то же что и на `0x8000000`, значит не мой случай.

Если там мусор (точнее, системный загрузчик), смотрим `SYSCFG->CFGR1` (обратите внимание, ему `clock` надо включить `RCC->APB2ENR|=RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGCOMPEN` иначе там всегда `0`) там младший бит - копия прочитанного при старте `BOOT0`.

Простейшее решение пока паяльник не согрелся - сами пишем туда `0` прежде чем разрешать прерывания.

P.S.: Топик стартер говорил про `Cortex-M4`, там все несколько иначе, но суть проблемы может быть та же, там вероятно надо смотреть регистр `VTOR`.